# Video stops buffering

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, buffering

I have a 4 videos and preloader, that should hide when all the videos is fully buffeder

```
<div id="preload">
    <h1>
        Download...
    </h1>
</div>
<video preload="auto" class="active">
<source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4;'>
</video>
<video  preload="auto">
<source src="video2.mp4" type='video/mp4;'>
</video>
<video preload="auto">
<source src="video3.mp4" type='video/mp4;'>
</video>
<video preload="auto">
<source src="video4.mp4" type='video/mp4;'>
</video>
```

There is the code that checks if videos is buffered

```
preload = [];
preloadOverlay = document.querySelector('#preload');
videos =  document.querySelectorAll("video")
    [...videos].forEach(function(video, index) {
        video.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
            let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
                // console.log(preload)
                // console.log(video.buffered.end(0), video.duration)
                if(preload.length < 4)
                {
                    if(video.buffered.end(0) === video.duration)
                    {
                        preload.push(index)
                    }
                    timerId = setTimeout(tick, 200);
                }
                else if(preload.length === 4)
                {
                    clearTimeout(timerId);
                    preloadOverlay.classList.add('hide');
                }
                
            }, 200);
        })  
    })
```

but sometimes buffering just stops, for example all the videos are 3 seconds long, but buffering stops at 2 second

i changed my code a little bit to

```
[...videos].forEach(function(video, index) {
    video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
        preload.push(index)
      });
      let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
        if(preload.length < 4)
        {
            console.log(preload)
            console.log(video.buffered.end(0), video.duration)
            timerId = setTimeout(tick, 200);
        }
        else if(preload.length === 4)
        {
            clearTimeout(timerId)
            preloadOverlay.classList.add('hide')
            layoutAnimation(timeoutClassRemover)
        }        
    }, 200);
})
```

but still, one or two videos does not load till the end, and stops randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the timer for this task. Promises look more suitable here from my perspective.

Also, I would recommend removing `;` at the end of types `video/mp4`.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
// just to make the snippet working
const testVideoUrl = 'https://r2---sn-ntqe6n7r.c.2mdn.net/videoplayback/id/97eca827be163084/itag/15/source/doubleclick/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/2144448000/sparams/expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mh,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source/signature/160FEBC1E31299C398B4F585BB3AC111D899FB8D.4E8EB91A32577DC9954E0EB1CED4109081DE6B71/key/cms1/cms_redirect/yes/mh/Hp/mip/60.241.173.252/mm/42/mn/sn-ntqe6n7r/ms/onc/mt/1679898045/mv/m/mvi/2/pl/23/file/file.mp4'

const preloadPromises = [];
const preloadOverlay = document.querySelector('#preload');
const videos =  document.querySelectorAll("video");
[...videos].forEach((video, index) => {
  // just for the test the URL is assigned from the script
  video.src = testVideoUrl;
  let resolve;
  const promise = new Promise((_resolve) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
  });
  video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', resolve);
  preloadPromises.push(promise);
});

// wait for all videos to precache
Promise.all(preloadPromises).then(() => {
  console.log('all the videos can be played through');
  // all the videos can be played through
  preloadOverlay.classList.add('hide');
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="preload">
      <h1>
        Download...
      </h1>
    </div>
    <video preload="auto" class="active">
      <source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <video  preload="auto">
      <source src="video2.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <video preload="auto">
      <source src="video3.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <video preload="auto">
      <source src="video4.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At this point i belive that the problem is not in the script, but with the server. With this code sometimes its stuck in pending forever, its mostly happens when you reload page and clear cache , but in most cases it work just fine

Comment: Try to monitor the `stalled` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/stalled_event
It could help to detect if the server is not providing more data when requested. I would also go through other `errors` / `progress` / `loading` related events here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events to see if something could give some cues. The network tab could also be helpful in some cases. Good luck!

Comment: @RAllen Maybe checking for IF [ReadyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is `== 4` that might also help? It could be an alternative to [CanPlayThrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) method, if that's being inconsistent.

Comment: @VC.One my guess is that `readyState` changes are firing events such as `canplaythrough`.